# get name of a variable from a string

Tags: javascript

So basically, have a prompt that asks for a property name, so you can then set its value. As shown here: (Also i know regex is the best way to do this however this is jsut a test for now)

```
if (command == "/set") {
  var property = prompt("Property:");
  var value = prompt("Set to:");
  if (typeof property.valueOf() === 'undefined') {
    var dontExist = alert("Property Doesnt Exists");
  } else {
    property.valueOf() = value;
  }
}
```

this is what i have so far, but it doesnt work. Thanks for the help ahead of time.

Comment: `property.valueOf() = value;` That's not going to work. Why are you using `valueOf`? Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: You can use an object and the `[ ]` operator. That will let you use the "property" variable to be used to select an object property name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are your properties stored?

If you store them in an Object, you can check if it exists with .hasOwnProperty() and then assign the property using the string directly.

e.g.

```
var properties = {};
if(command == "/set"){
    var property = prompt("Property:");
    var value = prompt("Set to:");
    if (properties.hasOwnProperty(property) {
        properties[property] = value;
    } else {
        alert("Property Doesnt Exists")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Answered!

just use window[property]

takes the string inside of the variable property, and turns it into the variable.